# Showing both date and time in a single column

Tags: csv, text-formatting

I am extracting time series data from NetCDF using  Climate data operator.
It has the option to extract Date as well as time separately.
I have used

```
cdo -outputtab,date,time,value -remapnn,lon=-85.25_lat=31.57  -select,name=pr pr.sample.nc> out1.csv
```

However, I have like to merge this date and time in a single column.

[image]

Here is my input.csv

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1C7XWGXafu1coNICK55AA-GzdM9DqnbuA?usp=sharing

Comment: Showing some sample CSV input & output lines would help answerers address your question more directly. Thank you!

Comment: Your `csv` file isn't `csv`, it's just space separated text in a single field and your `png` shows that you want to have a far from standard date format. If you want help with the whole problem then post the whole question along with what you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If its CSV :

you could use `awk` , Try this if it works :

```
awk 'FNR==1{ row=$2","$3$4","$5;print row  } FNR!=1{ row=$1","$2$3","$4; print row}' input.csv
```

Comment: It's not working with me. It inserts a blank row to each row.

Comment: @b_takhel : Updated the answer , try that and let me know

Comment: Still, it's the same with the one you ave provided before. Thanks though for your effort.

Comment: are you running that in linux?

Comment: i couldn't believe that , because for me it works fine...

Comment: huhh...your field delimiter is not `,` . not it should work , the same file is working for me..

Comment: yes, I am working in Linux.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109842/discussion-between-stalin-vignesh-kumar-and-b-takhel).

Answer (score 0):

If your input file is as linked it is not a `csv` it is space separated

```
#    name       date     time    value 
      pr  2006-01-01 12:00:00 0.002509068 
      pr  2006-01-02 12:00:00 0.8440843 
      pr  2006-01-03 12:00:00 0.3695453 
      pr  2006-01-04 12:00:00 6.589583 
      pr  2006-01-05 12:00:00 16.20289 
      pr  2006-01-06 12:00:00 0.1449011 
      pr  2006-01-07 12:00:00 29.98764 
      pr  2006-01-08 12:00:00 18.44757
```

and

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS=","}
  NR==1{print $2,$3"-"$4,$5}
  NR>1{split($2,d,"-");print $1, int(d[2])"/"d[3]"/"d[1]$3, $4}' input.csv
```

will give you

```
name,date-time,value
pr,1/01/200612:00:00,0.002509068
pr,1/02/200612:00:00,0.8440843
pr,1/03/200612:00:00,0.3695453
pr,1/04/200612:00:00,6.589583
pr,1/05/200612:00:00,16.20289
pr,1/06/200612:00:00,0.1449011
pr,1/07/200612:00:00,29.98764
pr,1/08/200612:00:00,18.44757
```

with the date `split` and recomposed as per the `png`

When redirected to `> out.csv` this will open in separate columns as per the `png`

Comment: If you are feeling generous and it works then you could always exercise your voting finger.....

Comment: I did it but my reputation is <15.SO, I could not show here. I gave an answer to the previous @stalin code. I would have done it too if allow me.

Comment: No worries but please post your code samples next time ;)